# How to reset React state from an error boundary recovery?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-query, react-error-boundary

My application has a user input a query to make a request to the Pokemon API and the response data is rendered.

If a user inputs a query that doesn't exist in the database, it will trigger the error boundary and a `Try Again` button to recover from the error by resetting the query state and have the user resubmit a different query. This is the intended behavior.

However, with my current setup, when the user's query does not have any matches, the console will show `GET https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/foo 404` and `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404`. The user does not see this error though. Nothing to tell the user that their query does not have any matches. I'm aiming to have a more explicit user experience telling the user their submitted request does not have any matches and to click the `Try Again` button to reset the input and submit a new query. I believe, this is what the error boundary should be doing.

I'm using the following libraries: `React Query, React Hook Form, React Error Boundary`. I've been suggested to use React Query's `onError` callback for logging errors and set the property `useErrorBoundary: true`. Still no luck.

Here's a working example to demonstrate the intended behavior. https://epic-react-exercises.vercel.app/react/hooks/3

Here's my attempt. Please let me know how to solve this. https://codesandbox.io/s/pokedex-5j1jf

```
const ErrorFallback = ({ error, resetErrorBoundary }) => {
  return (
    <div role="alert">
      <p>Something went wrong:</p>
      <pre style={{ color: "red" }}>{error.message}</pre>
      <button onClick={resetErrorBoundary}>Try again</button>
      <p>This error was caught by the error boundary!</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const searchSchema = yup.object().shape({
  pokemonName: yup.string().required()
});

const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [pokemonCharacter, setPokemonCharacter] = useState({});
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(searchSchema)
  });

  const handlePokemonFetch = () => {
    return axios(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${query}`).then((res) => {
      setPokemonCharacter(res.data);
    });
  };

  const { loading, error } = useQuery("pokemon", handlePokemonFetch, {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    enabled: false,
    useErrorBoundary: true,
    onError: (error) => console.log(error)
  });

  console.log(watch(pokemonCharacter));

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handlePokemonFetch)}>
                    <label htmlFor="Pokemon">Pokémon Character</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="pokemonName"
                        ref={register}
                        onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
                    />
                    {errors.pokemonName && <span>This field is required</span>}
                    {error && <p>Error occurred: {error.message}</p>}
                    <button type="submit">Search Pokémon</button>
                </form>
      </div>
            <ErrorBoundary
        FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}
        onReset={() => {
          setQuery("");
        }}
        resetKeys={[query]}
      >
        <div>
          {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
          <PokemonInfo pokemonCharacter={pokemonCharacter} />
        </div>
      </ErrorBoundary>
            <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={true} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please post a minimized set of working code in your question body. In the future, your links may no longer work, so we want the question to be able to stand alone.

Comment: @y2bd Sure thing, I just added the code.

Comment: Could that not be handled in a `.catch` statement in `handlePokemonFetch`?

Comment: @WebbH React-Query expects a failed promise so no catch method as it will make it a resolved promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the way you are using the error boundary.

If we look at the docs of react-error-boundary, we see the following:

> The simplest way to use  is to wrap it around any component that may throw an error. This will handle errors thrown by that component and its descendants too.

In your example the component that throws the error is the component that renders the `ErrorBoundary`. But in order for this to work, the component that throws the error should be a child of the `ErrorBoundary`.

I created a slightly different sandbox to illustrate this. https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-poincare-06e6v

Comment: Thank you for your example. Please check the updated Codesandbox, as I implemented your suggestion. However, it's not working with how my code is setup.

Comment: You are missing a few things from your updated sandbox: 1. the useQuery hook must be used within the <SearchForm /> component. 2) you are imperatively calling the handlePokemonFetch function. 3) your useQuery hook is not used because enabled: false.

Comment: What you need to do is to move the useQuery hook inside the SearchForm, and then onSubmt to setQuery and enable the useQuery hook only when query is not empty

Comment: I appreciate your continued help. I moved the `useQuery` logic into <SearchForm />. For your suggestion, I had removed `enabled:false`. I originally had it set there to prevent running a query when mounting. Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by `onSubmt to setQuery`. I've again updated the codesandbox.

Comment: You are not fetching the data using useQuery, you are directly calling the handlePokemonFetch function. Have a look at my example on how to properly use the enabled property to trigger a fetch only after the user has typed something

Comment: The app nows triggers the error boundary, thank you! Lastly, how do I recover from the error boundary by resetting the input query and having the user resubmit a request. I noticed, by setting `useQuery's retry: true`, it will reset the input query and have the user resubmit a request, but the error boundary is not triggered. Setting  `useQuery's retry: false` triggers the error boundary, but does not recover by resetting the input query.

Comment: The app nows triggers the error boundary, thank you! Lastly, how do I recover from the error boundary by resetting the input query and having the user resubmit a request. I noticed, by setting useQuery's retry: true, it will reset the input query and have the user resubmit a request, but the error boundary is not triggered. Setting useQuery's retry: false triggers the error boundary, but does not recover by resetting the input query. Please take a look at the updated code.